# Create Facebook Campaign and Get Campaign ID - Marketing API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

This is how facebook tells people to create a campaign according to the documentation: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/

However, what is the null field parameter inside the new Campaign constructor? Anything I put in there becomes the Campaign's ID, but an invalid one.
How do you get the campaign's ID?

When I run this code, I get no errors, but nothing is created on my Ads Manager, and when i echo $campaign->id it is just blank, because the id is null. However, if i print_r($campaign) it returns a large object with many fields, but no ID field.

Facebook code:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CampaignFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\CampaignObjectiveValues;

$campaign = new Campaign(null, 'act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>');
$campaign->setData(array(
CampaignFields::NAME => 'My campaign',
CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE => CampaignObjectiveValues::LINK_CLICKS,
));

$campaign->create(array(
 Campaign::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Campaign::STATUS_PAUSED,
));
```

Here is the facebook documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/using-the-api

However, it isn't very useful because it just points to a quick start guide that gives no relevant information.

Comment: The first parameter is the campaign ID. This is if you want to fetch an existing campaign by it's ID and should not be set when creating new campaigns.

Comment: That helps, however I dont understand why echo $campaign->id at the end of the code doesnt show anything?

Comment: This is a stab in the dark (after reading the SDK-code), try `$newCampaign = $campaign->getSelf(); echo $newCampaign->id`.

Comment: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'field 'id' is required.' "   This must be a permissions issue or something.

Comment: Hm. How about: `$camp = $campaign->create(array(...)); echo $camp->id;`? It looks like it returns the same object, though. It's still a strange behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The facebook examples are incomplete. Make sure your initiate the Facebook Ad API.

If the creation was successful the Facebook library assigns the id to the campaign object you called create() on and it can be accessed as follows:

```
$campaign->{CampaignFields::ID};
```

Here is a full example of how to create a campaign:

```
   // 1. The facebook api has to be initiated before making request
    Api::init("App Id", "App Secret", "User Token");

    $campaign = new Campaign(null, 'act_<account id>');

    // 2. Populating the campaign object
    $campaign->setData([
        CampaignFields::NAME => 'TEST Campaign',
        CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE => CampaignObjectiveValues::LINK_CLICKS
    ]);

    try {

        // 3. If the operation is successful the id will be set
        $campaign->create();

        // Grabbing the id.
        $facebookCampaignId = $campaign->{CampaignFields::ID};

        // Printing the id
        var_dump($facebookCampaignId);
    } catch (RequestException $requestException) {

        // Can be null
        $facebookResponse = $requestException->getResponse();

        if (!empty($facebookResponse)) {

            // Its easier to debug using the response by Facebook.
            var_dump($facebookResponse->getBody());
        }

    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        var_dump($exception->getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the id with $campaign->id, after you call the create method. Check if you get some error, maybe you don't get id because campaign is not created.

If you are looking for PHP SDK doc it is here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk

Try this example:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CampaignFields;

try{
    $campaign  = new Campaign(null, $account->id);
    $campaign->setData(array(
        CampaignFields::NAME => 'My First Campaign',
        CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE => 'LINK_CLICKS',
    ));
    $campaign->validate()->create(array(
        Campaign::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Campaign::STATUS_PAUSED,
    ));
    echo "Campaign ID:" . $campaign->id . "\n";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error message: ' .$e->getMessage() ."\n" . "<br/>";
    echo 'Error Code: ' .$e->getCode() ."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: When you do this does the campaign show up in your Ads Manager? Did you have to apply for any extra permissions? Are you using Graph API to get your account Id?